Elastic Beanstalk Container Commands Not Executing on Docker (Amazon Linux 2023)
I'm deploying an application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using Docker on the Amazon Linux 2023 platform, configured without a Load Balancer and on a Single Instance.
I have several .ebextensions configuration files with container commands to install Certbot and set up HTTPS, but they aren't executing during deployment.
I followed the setup from this Medium article.
I've verified the YAML syntax and checked logs (/var/log/eb-activity.log, /var/log/docker.log, cfn-init-cmd.log, /var/log/cfn-init.log) for errors, but there's no output indicating the commands are running.
Has anyone encountered similar issues? How can I ensure my container commands are executed during deployment? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated!
